# In-grown nail or something stuck in his toe?

Tags: leopard-geckos

[image]

I noticed this after he shed.
Is this an in-grown nail or something else? It seems to be irritated, and red, at the tip of the toe where the object (nail?) Begins. But the rest of his claws are white. 
Has anyone else seen this before?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like he had a few issues with his shed and irritated the toe.  Give him nice warm water soaks daily until it clears up.  A dab of neosporin should help too.  If it gets worse, take him to the vet.

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange :) Is neosporin safe for a leopard gecko? Perhaps a source stating that would help backup your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but this looks a lot like what I just dealt with. I think I actually just went through this with one of mine. I had to check it out a little bit and found out that the gecko had actually bitten herself trying to get some stuck shed off. She has been a problem shedder from day one. To make a long story short, antibiotic ointment wasn't enough and we ended up in the vet's office anyways and walked out with a week's worth of antibiotics. Unfortunately it wasn't enough in my particular case (your case could differ from mine). We ended up going back for stronger antibiotics a few weeks later. My advice, cut to the chase and head to an experienced vet who is knowledgeable about reptiles ASAP. They can get it taken care of and save you some worry and money in the long run.

Comment: I agree that going to the vet is the best course of action in this case. Better to be safe than sorry.